# For loop not executing (trying to alter a variable every time "11" appears in list) BLACKJACK

Tags: python

I need to code a way to determine whether or not a blackjack hand is a bust, and if it isn't, I need to return the sum of the hand. My for loop does not appear to be working. I am trying to subtract 10 from the sum of the hand if there is an 11 (Ace) in the hand, and the original sum of the hand is greater than 21. I am aware that right now the variable 'newsum' will be printed twice. This was for me to determine if the for loop was running properly.

```
blackjack = [5,11,7]
newsum = sum(blackjack)
if sum(blackjack) <= 21:
    print(sum(blackjack))
elif sum(blackjack) > 21:
    for n in blackjack:
        if n == 11:
            newsum = newsum - 10
            print(newsum)
        break
        newsum <= 21
    if newsum <= 21:
        print(newsum)
    else:
        print("BUST")
```

Comment: It seems like your loop is checking if `11` is present in the `blackjack` structure - why not just use the `in` operator? Why the additional time complexity?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
blackjack = [5, 11, 7]
newsum = sum(blackjack)
if sum(blackjack) >= 21:
    for card in blackjack:
        if card == 11:
            newsum = newsum - 10
    if newsum >= 21:
        print(f"BUST (Your Hand: {sum(blackjack)})")
    else:
        print("Your Hand:", newsum)
else:
    print("Your Hand:", sum(blackjack))
```

You just needed to remove the break statement, really.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your for loop is executing, it's just that your break statement breaks out of the loop on the first go around. you may want to indent the break statement into your if statement.